# what does calling Object without using new do?

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

I've seen code that goes along the line of

```
Object( existingObject ).myMethod();
```

Is this different than calling `existingObject.myMethod()` directly? More generally, what does Object(x) do?

Comment: It creates an object wrapper

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Object constructor creates an object wrapper for the given value.
>   If the value is null or undefined, it will create and return an empty
>   object, otherwise, it will return an object of a type that corresponds
>   to the given value. If the value is an object already, it will return
>   the value.

In your case, since the value is an object already, it will just return the value `existingObject`. So, no, it is not really different from calling `existingObject.myMethod` directly.

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

Comment: You should provide a link to quotes. In particular, the phrase "The Object constructor creates…" should really be "When called as a function, the Object constructor creates…" to more closely align with [ECMA-262](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.1.1).